# What is mutually disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

What is mutually disjoint sets?

I know it has something to do with subsets but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a family of sets. We say that the sets in $\mathscr{A}$ are *mutually disjoint* if no two of them have any elements in common. In other words, if $A,B\in\mathscr{A}$, and $A\ne B$, then $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Another term that means the same thing is *pairwise disjoint*.

In pictorial terms, if you make a [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) of the sets, you’ll have a bunch of non-overlapping circles.

Comment: Brian's answer and this one ([Does ‘disjoint’ mean pairwise or collectionwise?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4012997/21813)) nicely supplement each other.